# Smallest value of a graphed circle?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions

So I have a question saying, "Find the smallest value of $$
x^2 + y^2  -2x + 6y + 3= 0."
$$ 
I know how to make this into a circle equation 
$$(x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 =7$$ 
(if I'm not wrong) and graph it, but where and how do I find the smallest value on this circle?

any answers appreciated :)

Comment: That question, as written, makes no sense. It's like saying "Find the smallest value of $2 = 2$"; the thing you're trying to "evaluate" is an equality, hence is either true or false. And there isn't a notion of "smaller" between the values "true" and  "false". Are you certain you've transcribed the question exactly as it was written?

Comment: The "smallest value of a equation" doesn't make sense; that's usually the language for functions, or of variables under a constraint. Is there missing context, such as "the smallest y-value" for which the equation holds?

Comment: By the way, your circle-formula appears to be wrong; I think that the right-hand side should be $7$ rather than $13$.

Comment: Yep, that's the whole question. Just to clarify, finding the smallest value for a circle doesn't make sense but is finding the smallest value for a  parabola possible? (ps thanks for checking my equation!)

Comment: Also: I replaced the second "x" in your circle-equation with the $y$ that you intended to write, and put in that $7$ instead of $13$.

Comment: No... neither fo those things makes sense. I suspect that David Peterson's conjecture might be what's meant, but...who knows? It may be time to get a new teacher/book.

Comment: @JohnHughes Perhaps the question intends to mean finding the smallest values of $(x,y)$? That can be found by letting $x=0$ and then $y=0$, and then solving for $y$ and $x$ respectively through quadratics.

Comment: isn't the circle equation (x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2 ?

Comment: @MrPie thanks, I'll try that

Comment: If you know the center and the radius of a circle, Maths, then can't you see what the lowest point of the circle will be? I think that's what the question is asking.

Comment: @MrPie: Is there some ordering on ordered pairs? Or do you mean "the smallest possible value of $x$ and also the smallest possible value of $y$, even though these two  minimum-achieving values, taken together, do not constitute a solution to the equation"? I suppose that *could* be what was intended...but that's not a math question; it's a **mind-reading** question. Hence my suggestion about new books/teachers.

Comment: Also @MrPie: setting $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ doesn't actually determine the minimum values. Setting $x = 1$ (to get $y = -3 \pm\sqrt{7}$) and $y = -3$ (to get $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{7}$) does that.

Comment: You actually raise a good point. Tbh I'm not sure how to find the minimum or maximum global point on a circle, and wasn't sure if it was accomplishable, but I can on quadratics (that is the easiest, actually). But your focus on the structural phrasing of the question is leading me to be of the same opinion as you.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about the modulus of x and y coordinates.
As the modulus of a point increases with radial distance from the origin we construct a line joining origin and centre of circle and find the point of intersection of the circle with this line. which gives the point of intersection as 0.163 i - o.49 j which is the minimum value of the modulus of a point lying on the circle.